# Does anyone know where I can find the mapping between diesel data type and Rust primitive type?

Tags: postgresql, rust-diesel

I am using diesel ORM for my rest api service. I am running into compilation issue saying "the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `f64`".

I have NUMERIC for price column in my PostgreSQL database table; Numeric for price field in the diesel::table! schema generated by diesel migration run; and I have f64 primitive type for price in pub struct CostItems.

I have tried "double precision" for db table; Float8 in schema generated by diesel migration run; and f64 primitive type for struct CostItems. Same error.

I have tried "money" for db table; Money in schema generated by diesel migration run; and both f64 and f32 primitive types for struct CostItems. Same error.

Is there any documentation that actually provide the mapping between diesel sql_types and Rust primitive type? Or any suggestion on how I may overcome this compilation error is greatly appreciated? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general deserialization mechanism in diesel is explained [here](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/index.html#serializing-and-deserializing).
Each type in `diesel::sql_types` lists compatible rust types. So for example for [`numeric` see here](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/sql_types/struct.Numeric.html) and for `money` see here

Comment: Thank you weiznich. I have asked other people online and a lot of them suggested to use bigdecimal::BigDecimal instead of f64. I did that but doesn't seem to help. I am getting error like:

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(i64, std::string::String, BigDecimal, std::string::String): FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>), Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/cost_items/model.rs:66:50

Comment: 66   |         let cost_items = match query.get_results(&mut conn) {
     |                                      ----------- ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Numeric, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>), Pg>` is not implemented for `(i64, std::string::String, BigDecimal, std::string::String)`
     |                                      |
     |                                      required by a bound introduced by this call

Comment: By the way, I have the code in github, if you need more details on what I was trying to do.
https://github.com/cchee/rust-tryout

Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: There is really not much to add to my answer above: Each of the types in `diesel::sql_types` list the compatible rust types. For `diesel::sql_types::Numeric` that is `bigdecimal::BigDecimal`. Given that your question does not contain a minimal example it's really hard to add anything else here.

Comment: Thank you weiznich, I figured out what was my problem and already committed the change to the github link. Basically, I was missing Option<> for one of the field when the database table allows NULL for the field.